# Ember RC1: need access to view in route event

Tags: ember.js

In previous versions of Ember, the javacsript event object would be passed as a parameter to the event handling function of the route. In RC1 it is no longer passed. I also can not find any way to get the view object from the route. I am build a form to upload a file to the backend datastore using the FormData object.  I know I could handle the event within the view rather than the route, but I would prefer to handle all events that change router state in the router itself.

This code worked in previous versions:

```
add_asset: Ember.Route.extend({
   upload: function(router, event) {
      var form = event.target.form;
      var view = event.view;
      var form_data = new FormData(form);
      var uploadModel = new App.Asset();
      var success_callback = function(){
         console.log('uploaded!');
         router.transitionTo('root.portfolios.show_portfolio', event.context)
      };
      var error_callback = function() {
         console.log('error uploading');
      };
      uploadModel.upload(form_data, success_callback, error_callback);
  }
});
```

I am unable to find a way to get either the event object or view object from with the route event handler. Is this possible? Thanks.